# MYSQL Weird syntax error with/without semicolons

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

The following code is for an assignment of mine.
I get weird syntax errors on line 3 saying that CREATE is not a valid input, so I try to put a semi-colon or try to fix it somehow and it'll move down to the SET general_log on line 7 and say the same error for that.

```
USE assignment2;

CREATE TABLE log (
    general_log VARCHAR(255)
);

SET global general_log = 1;
SET global log_output = 'table';

SOURCE dbchange2.sql;

SET GLOBAL general_log = 0;

SELECT CONCAT(general_log) AS Log
FROM log;

SELECT general_log, COUNT(general_log)
FROM log
ORDER BY general_log ASC;
```

Comment: So what is your **actual** question? Yes, MySQL uses semicolon as statements delimiter.

Comment: You have to put a semi-column at end of each statement.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i'm getting a syntax error on line 10 where the SOURCE is, I've got semi-colons where they need to be now but i'm still getting an error there.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running all this together? where are all the semicolons `;` ???

Try this:

```
USE assignment2;

CREATE TABLE log (
    general_log VARCHAR(255)
);

SET global general_log = 1;
SET global log_output = 'table';

SOURCE dbchange2.sql;

SET GLOBAL general_log = 0;

SELECT CONCAT(general_log) AS Log
FROM log;

SELECT general_log, COUNT(general_log)
FROM log
ORDER BY general_log ASC;
```

If that doesn't work, try wrapping the query with `DELIMITER`

```
DELIMITER //

--CODE HERE

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Sorry I initially did have semi-colons on all the lines but removed them to see if that was the source of the problem. Now the same error comes up on line 10 with the SOURCE

Comment: So try adding a `DELIMITER` @SlavkoBojanic

Comment: OK, i've added the delimiters, now when the code is executed i'm getting an error saying that the way i'm executing my SOURCE command doesn't correspond to my SQL version (even though it does, i've used it many times before)